# Are operations permitted as function arguments?

Tags: php

I have a function foo which accepts one argument.

```
function foo ($argument){
  return $argument;
}
```

I tried to the following:

```
$result = foo ($variable + $variable2 + 1);
```

(a sum with two integer variables plus an integer)

But results were unexpeccted.

However, if I try:

```
$result = foo ($variable +  1);
```

(a sum with an integer variable and an integer)

it works. Why is this so? What (where?) are the rules for such usage?

As a test i tried;

```
$variable3 = $variable + $variable2;
$result = foo ($variable3 +  1);
```

The creation of var3 works as expected, making me think the variables are valid but the use of function arguments was not.

Comment: Make sure `$variable2` is an integer. You can debug by doing `$test = $variable + $variable2 + 1` and then running `foo($test)`

Comment: Yes, they should be. Try doing what I said with `$test` to see if the problem is with passing the integers or if it is the integer itself

Comment: @Gamemorize What is your goal with foo? what you expect to return? and as i said please post the function and the error message

Comment: @Gamemorize this should work both! Did you defined these 2 variables? What php version your using?

Comment: @Gamemorize please post your exact code where you using the function and whats the exact error message is! As you can see here it should work: http://3v4l.org/OONYe

Comment: @Gamemorize As i said please post the code where your using the function and whats the exact error message is! Because it has to work!

Comment: @Rizier, the fiddle is perfect, post it as an answer thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function must work!

Here the link that it works for many php version:

http://3v4l.org/mLMks

See these examples it even doesn't makes a difference if a variable is a string or even text!

(number as string)

```
<?php

    function foo ($argument){
      return $argument;
    }

    $variable = "2";
    $variable2 = 3;
    echo $result = foo ($variable + $variable2 + 1);


?>
```

Output

```
6
```

(number and text)

```
<?php

    function foo ($argument){
      return $argument;
    }

    $variable = 2;
    $variable2 = "test";
    echo $result = foo ($variable + $variable2 + 1);


?>
```

Output

```
3
```

Comment: THanks! I had been trying your fiddle too with strings and yep it worked. Clearly something greater is amiss. Thank you for your confirmation!